# Rails render partial dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm getting a bit crazy with this, I have a **Event** who *has_many* **Attendants** but I haven't been able to create dynamically inside the Event form, I have a **partial** with the *form* of Attendant, this works:

```
<%= form.fields_for :attendants do |form_attendant| %>
  <%= render 'form_attendant', form_attendant: form_attendant %>
<% end %>
```

for 1 attendant, if I copy-paste that, it works for 2 and so on..

I want a button to do that for me, I've read and tried a loooot.

**Option 1:**
I have tried in js to append that, with:

```
$("#attendants").append "<%= form.fie ... %>"
```

but It just print the text and won't render the partial, I have tried with *escape_javascript* too with no luck.

**I'm now trying with:**

```
<%= link_to "Agregar", new_attendant_path, remote: true %>
```

I have these in attendants/new.js.erb

```
$('#attendants').append("<%= escape_javascript ( render partial: 'form_attendants' ) %>");
```

Which actually works and render the partial but now I don't know how to send the local *event form* so I can make 
`<%= form.fields_for :attendants do |form_attendant| %> ...`  inside the partial,

Any help would be appreciated, I'm almost crying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) it will do all this stuffs

Answer (score 1):

Try [nested_form_fields](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) gem

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.nested_fields_for :videos do |ff|
    = ff.remove_nested_fields_link
    = ff.text_field :video_title
    ..
  = f.add_nested_fields_link :videos
```

You can change the link text of *remove_nested_fields_link* and *add_nested_fields_link*, add classes/attributes, etc...

You can also customize the add/remove functionality, by overriding the

**[nested_form_fields.js.coffee](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/nested_form_fields.js.coffee)** into your rails JavaScript asset

for more info

https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields

```
<%= form_for @users do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :attendants do |form_attendant| %>
   <%= render 'form_attendant', form_attendant: form_attendant %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :attendants %>
<% end %>
```

partial _form_attendant.html.erb

```
<%= form_attendant.remove_nested_fields_link %>
<%= form_attendant.text_field :attd_date %>
<%= form_attendant.text_field :attd_time %>
```